# Cordova problems with google map

Tags: javascript, android, google-maps, cordova, google-maps-api-3

I'm developing an app whit phonegap (cordova). This app includes a google map with some markers.
The app also has more pages as a list of comerces…

The map shows correctly, but when I change the page, and back to the map page, sometimes the map is displaced and the info windows not open correctly.

Is there any way to put a map and it appears correctly when changing pages?

And I have also seen that the map consuming a lot internet data.
Could someone make me a suggestion?

I hope someone can help me!!
Thanks, and excuse me for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems with google maps and cordova. I was using jquery-mobile and sometimes if you switch between pages the maps wasn't loaded properly. You can check out different page events and try to "resize" the maps. I was also playing with different version of cordova and jquery-mobile. [This](https://code.google.com/p/jquery-ui-map/) could help as well.

```
$(document).on("pagebeforeshow","#pagetwo",function(){
  google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

best

M